# TextAreaField renders with itself (HTML code in readable text format) as its prepopulated text value

Tags: html, textarea, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm rendering a `WTForms TextAreaField`s with `Jinja2` in a `Flask` application and it has it's own HTML code as its prepopulated text value, although the default property (which should specify the prepopulated value) is set to empty string `''`.

Form definition:

```
channels = TextAreaField('channels', default='')
```

Jinja2 template HTML file:

```
{% for c in e.form.conditions %}
    {{ c.form.channels }}
{% endfor %}
```

Result (rendered, visible to end-user, should be empty string `''`):

```
<textarea id="channels" name="channels"></textarea>
... (other iterations)
```

Result (HTML):

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="conditions-0-channels" name="conditions-0-channels">&lt;textarea id="channels" name="channels"&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt;</textarea>
... (other iterations)
```

I double-checked using the Pycharm debugger and the TextAreaField as a whole object shows as the HTML result above, even though none of its properties contain the visible result string (also above), and the `default` property is equal to `''` even though the result doesn't show so.

Bonus hint: for some reason, if the form containing the `channels` field is not part of a `FormField` inside a `WTForms FieldList`, this problem *does not occur*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what on earth is going wrong with this combination of `FieldList`, `FormField` and `TextAreaField`, but if you call `{{ c.form.channels.data }}` (with extra *.data*) in your Jinja2 template HTML file instead of `{{ c.form.channels }}` then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Wow THANK YOU! I'm not sure what's going on either but this solved the issue for me too. I had some similar findings shown below:

Forms.py

```
class ChannelForm(FlaskForm):
    notes = TextAreaField('Notes', render_kw={'class': 'form-control'}, default="")
```

channels.html

```
# These:
{{ channels.notes.data }} # Working solution
{{ channels.notes(value="test Value") }}

# Render these:
<textarea class="form-control" id="notes" name="notes"></textarea>
<textarea class="form-control" id="channels-0-notes" name="channels-0-notes" value="Test Value">&lt;textarea class="form-control" id="notes" name="notes"&gt;
Test</textarea>
```